# PHP include error when calling script from CLI

Tags: php, cmd, include, command-line-interface, parse-error

I'm trying to call from CLI a php script that include the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), I've two files:

File test.php

```
<?php
echo exec('php -f script.php');
?>
```

File script.php

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$ob = new simple_html_dom();
?>
```

On PHP 5.5.12 this works perfectly, but on a server that runs PHP 5.5.18 I got the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in
>   /path/to/simple_html_dom.php on line 117

Line 117 is:

```
public $nodetype = HDOM_TYPE_TEXT;
```

This constante is declared in line 48 as:

```
define('HDOM_TYPE_TEXT',    3);
```

I see no problem! I don't know why it's bugging in .18 and not in .12, I've tried everything, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your server is running with very old version of PHP
try this : `var_dump(shell_exec("php --version"));` or simply run phpinfo.php

Comment: indeed:
string(146) "PHP 4.4.9 (cgi) (built: Apr 20 2012 18:34:17) Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies "
Is the php cli version independant from the php version which is 5.5 on my server?

Comment: no, your server is running with PHP 4.4.9 and not with 5.5 as you said. are you the administrator of this server ? if yes : check if you have downloaded the right version of php, linking correctly your Apache server with your PHP and restarted your apache

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me a lot! No I'm not administrator, but apparently OVH runs by default two different versions for CLI and CGI!! I found that I have to call a newer version of php-cli by specifiying its entire path, now it works.

Comment: i am delighted to have helped you :)